# Curling Instagrams API

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to curl the url `https://www.instagram.com/<handle>/media/` to get my profiles data as json. How come when I hit this url in a browser I get the correct response but when I try to curl it using php as follows:

```
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/<handle>/media/";


$curl_connection = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

$json = curl_exec($curl_connection);
curl_close($curl_connection);

echo $json;
```

I do get a response:

```
{"status":"ok","items":[],"more_available":false}
```

however it is not very useful and not the same as I get when I hit the url in a browser.

This leads me to believe that I am not curling correctly.

Any suggestions?

FOLLOW UP:

I tried `file_get_contents($url);` which seems to give some users data correctly but for my account it does not.  Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using `file_get_contents` instead:

```
file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/derek/media/");
```

worked perfectly for me!

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: I just tried that and got the same response I posted in the question with my username but yours gave the correct response. Hmm

Comment: What's your handle? I'll test it in my environment

Comment: It's because your account is private. So unless you are logged into the account (or a follower, logged into that account), you cannot view anything that the account has posted.